# Input contains NaN

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I have been working on this categorical dataset to predict the fertilizer. I am getting the `input contains NaN` error even though I've dropped rows with any nan values. I really hope anyone could help me out with this.Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
    
features = pd.read_csv('Fertilizer Prediction.csv')
features.head(5)
    
features.dropna(how='any').shape
    
y = features['Name']
X = features.drop(columns=['Name'])
    
for col in X.dtypes[X.dtypes == 'object'].index:
    for_dummy = X.pop(col)
     X = pd.concat([X, pd.get_dummies(for_dummy, prefix=col)], axis=1)
    
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
    
y_train.values.ravel()
X_train.values.ravel()
    
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier
    
model().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[These are the screenshots of the error[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyRah.png)

The dataset I have used is from Kaggle and I'll link it below:
https://www.kaggle.com/gdabhishek/fertilizer-prediction?select=Fertilizer+Prediction.csv

Comment: Try creating a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with a small subset of the whole dataset, maybe you'll find the issue yourself

Comment: I could not reproduce. I've download dataset and applied your code, with some fixes (like name -> fert name) it works without any warning about nan.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`dropna`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-dropna/), you need to have `inplace=True` in order to drop the `NaN` and change the dataframe. Therefore given your code, you need to replace the line:

```
features.dropna(how='any').shape
```

with

```
features.dropna(how='any',inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Roshin Raphel. [What if someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).